# How to create text extruding from the center with Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, effects

I want to create 3D text with Adobe Illustrator which have camera depth of field. Simple 3D bevel/extrude effect gives me this:

[image]

Now I want to add some camera lense perspective effect, but not sure how to do this...

Update:

Example is 3D text

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Theoretically*** you should be able to use the **3D Extrude and Bevel Effect** in Illustrator for this. However, that effect - even after being more than 5 years old - still has some *major* issues with missing planes.

[image: 3d effect]

As you can see there are missing sides in the art. Sometimes you can alter one field slightly to make these sides appear. Occasionally, just adding 1° of rotation or altering the perspective by a small amount will suddenly make missing sides appear. But this isn't 100% either. It depends upon the artwork.

Another method is to use an **additional fill** via the **Appearance Panel** and scale and duplicate that fill with the `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform...` menu item.

[image: fill]

This works in all cases and there won't be any missing sides. But, this does not allow you to have gradients in the shadow area. You can expand and use pathfinder to unite the secondary fill shapes, then apply gradient manually though.

Comment: ah .. much better answer. I take solace in the fact that I chose the same "perspective" value :)

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for a long time. This is my illustrator 3D type  problem for years.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

The "3D Extrude & Bevel" effect has the option you are looking for ...
You need to enter a value for "Perspective". Higher values give stronger distortions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2 layers one is normal the second is blurred and use masks ( i think you got the idea ) same apply to photoshop  see the image i made one myself   hope this helps 
[image: sanp shot]

Comment: not exactly what I want. I've updated my question with an example.